# Why do I see a jump in my time series forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using `auto.arima()` from `forecast` package and am coming into some strange results with the prediction.

```
library(forecast)

x <- structure(c(1.92, 2.1, 1.73, 1.35, 1.29, 1.35, 1.42, 1.46, 1.6, 
1.67, 1.98, 1.78, 1.77, 2.35, 1.93, 1.43, 1.29, 1.26, 1.93, 2.33, 
2.22, 2.19, 2.15, 2.25, 3.12, 3.32, 2.72, 2.28, 2.28, 2.16, 2.81, 
3.12, 2.85, 2.98, 3.3, 3.06, 3.56, 3.81, 3.48, 2.64, 2.91, 3.35, 
3.73, 3.58, 4, 3.94, 3.79, 3.85), .Tsp = c(2012, 2015.91666666667, 
12), class = "ts")

fit <- auto.arima(x)

plot(forecast(fit, 12)) #forecast and actual data
f2 <- fitted.values(fit)
lines(f2, col="red") #add predicted values during training
```

[image]

I don't understand how fitted value (red line) is very close to observed value (black) but then there is a such a big jump in the first forecast.

Any ideas why we see this jump? I've seen other posts on Stack Exchange where the `xreg` option was used but this is not doing that so I haven't been able to track down a similar post.

Comment: No of course not. The question is why the gap between the last predicted value in red and the first predicted value in blue is so large. Is it simply that the lines aren't connected and the gap seems large or there is another issue? The predictions coming from the forecast() function are very off from 2016's actual data. The training predictions are quite close though. The jump from Dec to Jan is never this much.

Comment: I don't think there's any programming question here. Sounds like you might just be having problems interpreting the results of your model. If you have questions about the underlying statistical models, you should probably post your question to [stats.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I tend to believe that `auto.arima` slightly overfits data. Some quick exploratory analysis with ACF shows that `(0,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]` is already a decent model. I will use `arima0` from R base to fit this model:

```
fit0 <- arima0(x, order = c(0,1,2), seasonal = c(0,1,0))
```

Prediction / forecasting is done with `predict.arima0`:

```
pred <- predict(fit0, n.ahead = 12, se.fit = FALSE)
```

Let's plot observed series and forecast together:

```
ts.plot(x, pred, col = 1:2)
```

[image: arima0]

There is still a jump. But the variation is fairly reasonable, compared with the variability of the series.

**Nothing wrong.** When we forecast `x[49]` from `x[1:48]`, it will be different from `x[48]`. Typically, `(0,1,2)(0,1,0)[12]` has a linear trend plus a seasonal effect. It helps to visualize your time series and prediction season by season:

```
ts.plot(window(x, 2012, 2012 + 11/12),
        window(x, 2013, 2013 + 11/12),
        window(x, 2014, 2014 + 11/12),
        window(x, 2015, 2015 + 11/12),
        pred, col = 1:5)
```

[image: by season]